# Django how to filter queryset by a subclass using django model utils?

Tags: python, django, django-model-utils

I am using django-model-utils for inheritance Managers. I want to get results of only one subclass at a time.

managers.py

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager
class PostManager(InheritanceManager):
    pass
```

models.py

```
from .managers import PostManager
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField()
    objects = PostManager()


class ImagePost(Post, models.Model):
    source = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/%Y/%m/%d")


class VideoPost(Post, models.Model):
    source = models.URLField()
```

I want to return results of only image type. by writing a simpler query like this.

```
Post.objects.filter(type='image').select_subclasses()
```

What i have tried:

```
if type == 'image':
    Post.objects.filter(imagepost__isnull=False).select_subclasses()
```

This works but is kind of anti-pattern, i don't want to write conditions in views for every content type.

Is there better way like defining a property in models or converting it into a manager method? or am i missing something?

Comment: No such field 'type' in 'Post' model. Did you miss this field in 'Post' model?

Comment: `Post.objects.filter(imagepost__isnull=False).select_subclasses()` How does this work? Do you have a `ForeignKey` to `Post` in `ImagePost`? What is the purpose of `select_subclasses()`?

Comment: @Anoop : i want to do it this way, adding a static field 'type' won't give desired results too. In what way i can add that field in order to make it query-able.

Comment: @AKS: edited the question. I am using the Inheritance manager from django-model-utils https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to pass the class to `select_subclasses` method?

```
Post.objects.select_subclasses(ImagePost)
```

Check [their doc about this feature](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html).

**Edit:**

I misunderstood the question, but sounds like OP wants only the `Post` with type `ImagePost`. Doing `select_subclasses(ImagePost)` would fetch everything and convert the objects with type `ImagePost` to `ImagePost` instances. The solution should be as simple as :

```
image_posts = ImagePost.objects.all()
```

Comment: I was also just reading that. It seems that this will still result in all the objects just that the image posts will be the instances of `ImagePost` and rest of them will be the instances of `Post` class. Checkout this comment ... `restaurants will be Restaurant instances, bars will still be Place instance`

Comment: Hmm, I misunderstood your requirement. How about just doing `ImagePost.objects.filter(...)`? I know that it's repetitive to write multiple `if` statements but you might be able to get away with it by referring different models depend on what type do you have.

Comment: yup thats the way to do it. only doing select_subclasses(ImagePost) doesn't omit other results, so had to do this imagepost__isnull=False. ImagePost.objects.filter() is much cleaner. 
for removing if else, I defined it in url : {'content_class':ImagePost} and accessed it in view.
self.model = self.kwars.get('content_class')
self.model.objects.filter(...)
Thanks for your answer :)